# Apache Cannot bind to port 80

Tags: apache, webserver, port, bitnami

I'm trying to use **Bitnami MAPP Stack 5.5.30-0**
(For Apache Web Server, PostgreSQL)

When I try to configure the Apache Web Server I get this error: "Cannot bind to port 80. It is probably taken by another application or you don't have enough privileges.

I don't want to change and use another port. I really want to use the port 80.

I don't know what app is using the port 80.

I am running MAC OS X Yosemite

I tried this command:

```
sudo lsof -i ':80'
```

But nothing is running on this port.

I opened the httpd.conf and I tried to change the listen port to 80. But still not working.

Can someone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you already have **Apache** or **Nginx** running but you need to stop both of them before starting Apache with **XAMPP**. You can do this with:

To stop Apache: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop`

To stop Nginx: `sudo nginx -s stop`

Answer (score -1):

This means that you either have another process that is already using port 80 or you don't have enough privileges. The following unix command might shed some light. You can run it in terminal:

```
sudo lsof -i ':80'
```

Check out [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/597398/no-idea-what-is-listening-on-port-80-in-os-x) as well.

If it turns out that you don't have enough privileges, try to configure / run apache using sudo. (sudo stands for superuser do). Note: this maybe a quick fix to get you going on your local machine, but it is not recommended on a production machine.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, i tried this command on terminal but nothing is running. :(

Comment: Maybe it's a permission issue, see the edit to my answer.

Comment: How can I run apache on terminal? I opened the httpd.conf and I tried to change the listen port to 80. But still not working.

Comment: If is a privileges problem why is working with another port like the 8080 ?

Comment: In the port 80 nothing happens. I get the error  Safari Can't Connect to the Server.

Comment: Bitnami developer here, port 80 is reserved for administrator users, port 8080 is the default port for normal users. If you want to use port 80 you need to reinstall MAPP with sudo privileges.

Comment: I'm running with sudo and lsof -i ':80' is showing nothing but still I can't bind to port 80 on ipv4 (ipv6 is working)